# How to run rules in Outlook every 24 hours

Tags: outlook, outlook-2016

I'm currently working in a Production support . We will be getting more emails about the system CPU/RAM utilization, Job failures etc... Per day we will be receiving around 300 to 500 emails approx.We have filtered the email to go into different folders . However I do not want that to as soon as we get an email.

Because we focus only on the Inbox emails from Business Users.(approx 70 to 80 emails). However the email alerts or triggers should come to my inbox and stays there till 00:00 and then the rule should run and move the mails to corresponding inbox.How I can achieve that. is it possible to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just need to run a timer in Outlook VBA:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongLong, ByVal nIDEvent As LongLong, ByVal uElapse As LongLong, ByVal lpTimerfunc As LongLong) As LongLong
Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongLong, ByVal nIDEvent As LongLong) As LongLong

Public TimerID As LongLong 'Need a timer ID to eventually turn off the timer. If the timer ID <> 0 then the timer is running

Public Sub TriggerTimer(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idevent As Long, ByVal Systime As Long)
  MsgBox "The TriggerTimer function has been automatically called!"
End Sub


Public Sub DeactivateTimer()
Dim lSuccess As LongLong
  lSuccess = KillTimer(0, TimerID)
  If lSuccess = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The timer failed to deactivate."
  Else
    TimerID = 0
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub ActivateTimer(ByVal nMinutes As Long)
  nMinutes = nMinutes * 1000 * 60 'The SetTimer call accepts milliseconds, so convert to minutes
  If TimerID <> 0 Then Call DeactivateTimer 'Check to see if timer is running before call to SetTimer
  TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, nMinutes, AddressOf TriggerTimer)
  If TimerID = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The timer failed to activate."
  End If
End Sub
```

The VBA macro shown above is based on the `KillTimer` and `SetTimer` functions provided by Windows. The [SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) function creates a timer with the specified time-out value. The [KillTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-killtimer) function destroys the specified timer. An application can process `WM_TIMER` messages by including a WM_TIMER case statement in the window procedure or by specifying a `TimerProc` callback function when creating the timer. When you specify a `TimerProc` callback function, the default window procedure calls the callback function when it processes `WM_TIMER`. Therefore, you need to dispatch messages in the calling thread, even when you use `TimerProc` instead of processing `WM_TIMER`.

Please remember, to get the timer working correctly you need Outlook running on the system.

Comment: Sure .Thanks a lot . . Can we fetch the system time instead of (1000 * 60) .

Comment: At srtartup, you can get the current date-time and calculate the remaining time until midnight.

Comment: Thanks !! . I'm not sure how I can proceed with that. Let me try that out.

Comment: Still i do not know the solution for this . Anyhow thanks for helping me :)